# Distinguish IP alias from the return of getifaddrs function

Tags: c, linux, networking, ip

I want to get all ips with its aliases ips. For example: I have 3 ips: eth0, eth0:0, eth0:1. When I get by `getifaddrs()` or `ioctl(socket, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifconf)`, I only get 3 interfaces with the same name "eth0". How do I check which interface is alias interface?

P/s: I use linux base on Linux From Scratch!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Calling `getifaddrs` I get names like `eth0:1`, etc.

Comment: How did you add alias? I didn't use `ifconfig` because it don't work with reboot.

Comment: `ifconfig`. Perhaps the failure to assign unique names to each is a bug in `iproute2`...

Comment: Or rather perhaps that's the intended behavior of `iproute2`... In which case I think you just need to consider it "one interface with multiple addresses" or something...

Comment: I want to distinguish because the "real interface" use dhcp, and alias use static ip in a private network. So only real interface can change the `SERVICE=dhclient` or `SERVICE=ipv4-static`